# What is the logic behind url decoder when using double quotes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why does url decode not get an error when it decodes %22. This is a double quote. When a programmer enters a double quote in a string syntactically they must use two double quotes "" to represent a double quote.

For Example

```
string myString = "It\"s nice to meet you";
console.write(myString);
```

Output

**It"s nice to meet you**

But when url decodes a double quotes why does it not break. After the string is passed through the url decoder there is only a single quote ". Why does this not break the code?

For Example

```
 string myString = "It%22s nice to meet you";
 myString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myString);
 console.Write(myString);
```

Output

**It"s nice to meet you**

Comment: Strings are definitely capable of handling `It"s nice to meet you`. The requirement to escape quotes is *only* when hardcoding text in code. It exists because it tells the compiler whether you are *ending the string*, or *actually wanting to write a quote*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The need to escape double quotes is only a concern for literal strings in C#. The language is defined that way. Non-literals are not impacted: `((char)35).ToString() == "\""` is true.

This has no impact on the actual runtime values. `"\"".Length` is 1. The CLR is not aware of the escaping.

The CLR is capable of hosting many programming languages. It does not care about the escaping rules of a single language.

Library functions cannot even *tell* how you wrote or computed a string. Even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

The results are the same. They are just different representations of a double quote - depending on how you decode it.

```
// All the same:
string myString1 = @"It""s nice to meet you"; // string simplification
string myString2 = "It\"s nice to meet you"; // escaping a double quote
string myString3 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("It%22s nice to meet you");
```

Comment: so they all equal in the end It"s nice to meet you because the string in the decoded example is not being entered by literally. It doesnt need the escape  quotes.

Comment: Correct. Even more, during run-time all variables reference to the same position in the stack which holds the string `I"s nice to meet you`.